# Export contacts from a desktop application to a BlackBerry phone via USB

Tags: blackberry, export, contacts

I have to develop a module that exports contacts from a desktop application to a blackberry address book via USB connection.
I read about the IRimDatabaseAccess interface and the other RIM interfaces but I cannot figure out how to get initial access to the contacts database on a BB device from the desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

[BlackBerry Desktop Software](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/services/desktop/) can do [CSV import](http://www.blackberryforums.com.au/forums/bis-blackberry-desktop-manager/787-how-import-contacts-csv-file-blackberry-device.html) and export of contacts on the phone.  So one option would be to produce a CSV file and then just run the desktop software to import the contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know about this option but it should be something like this. When a user clicks a button labeled "Export to my Blackberry" (for example) in some contacts filtering form the contacts to be directly transfered to a Blackberry device connected to the user's computer via USB plus it is not necessary to install any additional software on the BlackBerry device so the contacts transfer to succeed.